# How to i user my google cloud API key in cloud functions in Python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I write cloud functions source now
my code need to my api key file

my key file is in google cloud storage
how to i invoek my key file from cloud storage?
and use code

```
KEY_PATH = ~ 
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(KEY_PATH)
client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project = credentials.project_id)
```

Comment: Why do you load credentials with keypath? In addition, why don't you use secret manager?

Answer (score 1):

It would be easiest to just reference the API key file locally unless there is some reason it must be pulled from Google Storage.

Comment: How to reference my api key in local?

Comment: I use my cloud functions in source code but idk about cloud function source invoek my api key

Comment: When first creating the api key, Google asks you to download it. I believe that is the only time it is offered to download, as they do not store the private key. You may need to make a new key to be prompted to download. You can download it in JSON or P12. I'm assuming you'll be wanting the JSON file. Download that and then assign that file path to KEY_PATH

Comment: already download my api key in local 
And Know to connect local python to bigquery 
but that is not connect in cloud functions source 
want to know that is in cloud function source invoke my api key file path(local, gcs)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use your key in a very simple way . Here is an example

```
    api_key = "your api key"  // put your key in a variable 

    api_endpoint = "endpoint url"  // endpoint

    params = {
       "key": api_key,
        // another parameters if an
    }

    result = request.get(api_endpoint, params}   // requset
```

Comment: api_key = "my_api_key"

what mean endpoint url?? 

params mean my api key file 'type', 'project_id', 'private_key_id' and more??

Comment: ap_key is a string type variable. api_endpoint is also string type and  is web address on which the backend server is running . Params is an object which is passedin get method where you place api_key and other required parameters like location etc.